# Custom-Posttype & Custom Taxonomy WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, page-template

I add a custom post type with custom taxonomy and i wish to get all postings into this by a template, but the result is 0

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'contents',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
      'taxonomy' => 'content-category',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => array(5,26,28)
  ),
  'meta_key' => 'fs16'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The SQL-Query is followed (don't know why):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = 'post_contents' JOIN wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code=l.code AND l.active=1 WHERE 1=1 AND 0 = 1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'contents' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'fsk16' ) AND t.language_code='en' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The `taxonomy`, `field` and `terms`  in `tax_query` should be two array-level deep instead of one. Quoted from the [WP_Query page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays
>   (it takes an array of arrays) - you can see this in the second example
>   below. This construct allows you to query multiple taxonomies by using
>   the relation parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the
>   boolean relationship between the taxonomy queries.

So, your arguments shoud be like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'contents',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
               'taxonomy' => 'content-category',
               'field' => 'id',
               'terms' => array(5,26,28)
        )
    ),
        'meta_key' => 'fs16'
);
```

You may omit `'post_status' => 'publish'` since it's the default value used anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to pass so many arguments?
The following should be sufficient to just display the posts of that category.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'contents', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

The above code is taken from the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).